# Cannot start SOLR on EC2 machine - does not detect gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I recently installed SOLR on my Amazon EC2 machine and when I try to start SOLR using `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start --trace`, I get the following message:

```
** Invoke sunspot:solr:run (first_time)
** Invoke sunspot:solr:moved_to_sunspot_solr (first_time)
** Execute sunspot:solr:moved_to_sunspot_solr

Note: This task has been moved to the sunspot_solr gem. 
To install, start and stop a local Solr instance, please add sunspot_solr to your Gemfile:

group :development do
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end
```

However, I've already included `sunspot_solr` in my Gemfile and my RAILS_ENV is production (I've also tried `export RAILS_ENV=production`. **Any tip as to why SOLR won't start and keeps trying to run in development?** I followed this link to install it - http://tanin.nanakorn.com/b/96/tomcat_and_solr_on_ec2

Here is part of my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'fuubar'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end
```

I've ran `bundle install` already and see that the gem is being used:

```
Using rsolr (1.0.8)
Using sunspot (1.3.0) 
Using sunspot_rails (1.3.0)
```

Comment: Are you generating the sunspot config file? Run the installer with the command `rails generate sunspot_rails:install`. If the problem persists try uninstalling and reinstalling sunspot. Also just to confirm you have the gem `sunspot_rails` included elsewhere in your GemFile, correct?

Comment: @CyleHunter I generated the xml configuration files myself. I tried running `bundle exec rails generate sunspot_rails:install` but it raised some other mysql errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sunspot_solr` gem is in your Gemfile's `:development` group, which Rails will ignore when you specify `RAILS_ENV=production`. The `sunspot_solr` gem is intended mostly as a convenience for development and testing, and is not particularly tuned for production, which is why the documentation suggests including it in the `:development` group.

If you have followed the steps described in the blog article that you linked, you actually don't need to use Sunspot's bundled Solr instance. By the end of that article, you should have a Solr server running on your server. (You'd have to double check the Tomcat configs to see which port it is running on.)

If I may be so bold, you might also benefit from considering a cloud hosted Solr search such as my own [websolr.com](https://websolr.com). You should be able to have an index up and running there within a few minutes.